# The react context from the child does not change

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-16

I read the solution from a similar question but it did not help.
Here is my simple code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-jennings-ugqzd

```
import myContext from "./myContext";
import Two from "./Two.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <myContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <div className="App">
          <Two />
          <h2>{this.state.number}</h2>
        </div>
      </myContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I need to set it up so it could be anywhere in class <Two /> change the variable number.
Help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just mutate state so

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.number = 100;
  }
```

If you mutate state react doesn't re render because you mutated it. You can do the following:

In App:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import myContext from "./myContext";
import Two from "./Two.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    };
  }
  increase = ()=> this.setState({number:this.state.number+1})

  render() {
    return (
      <myContext.Provider value={{...this.state,increase:this.increase}}>
        <div className="App">
          <Two />
          <h2>{this.state.number}</h2>
        </div>
      </myContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In Two:

```
import React from "react";

import myContext from "./myContext";

class Two extends React.Component {
  static contextType = myContext;

  render() {
    return (
      <myContext.Consumer>
        {({ number,increase }) => <h1 onClick={increase}>{number}</h1>}
      </myContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Two;
```